# Boolean Simplification Problem

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have to simplify the figure

[image]

I came up with the equation 
$$(ac+\bar b)\cdot (a+b+\bar c) \cdot (b+ac).$$

Help me out

**Attempted Answer:**

\begin{align*}
(ac+\bar b)\cdot (a+b+c)\cdot (b+ac)
&=(ac+abc+ac+a\bar b+\bar b c)\cdot(b+ac)\\
&=abc+abc+abc+ac+abc+ac+a\bar b c+a\bar b c \\
&=abc+a\bar b c+ac\\
&=ac(b+\bar b)+ac\\
&=ac+ac=ac
\end{align*}

Comment: What do you know about rules for manipulating these kinds of expressions? What laws are you allowed to use?

Comment: mm anything its just say simplfy

Comment: Well, I'm hoping your teacher and/or textbook explained *something* about how to go about doing that. [Karnaugh maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map), absorption laws, distributive laws? Anything?

Comment: its says but i usually prefer algebric method but this time i tried to do it and i ended up having the Answer: AC
but not sure its right answer or not !!!!

Comment: Ok i attached the photo of my attempt

Comment: The second factor is supposed to be $a+b+\bar c$, but you switched it to $a+b+c$ in your solution attempt.

Comment: Note: it would be better, in this case, to move your solution attempt to an answer section ("answer your own question"), because that way this question will show up as answered rather than staying in the unanswered queue forever and ever amen.

Comment: where is Answer your own question?

Comment: i cant do it .. they dont allowe me to put it !!!

Comment: It should be down at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here goes:

We need to simplify

$(ac + \bar b)(a + b + \bar c)(b + ac). \tag{1}$

I'll do this by a method which is a little different than the OP's, but will yield the same answer $ac$; this will corroborate k31453's work.  First, I observe that

$(ac + \bar b)(a + b + \bar c)(b + ac) = (ac + \bar b)(ac + b)(a + b + \bar c), \tag{2}$

and we have

$(ac + \bar b)(ac + b) = (ac)(ac) + acb + ac \bar b + \bar b b = ac + acb + ac \bar b, \tag{3}$

since $(ac)(ac) = ac$ and $\bar b b = 0$.  Next, I use

$acb + ac \bar b = ac(b + \bar b) = ac1 = ac \tag{4}$

to obtain

$(ac + \bar b)(ac + b) = ac + ac = ac. \tag{5}$

Substituting this back into (2) yields

$ac(a + b + \bar c) = ac + abc = ac(1 + b) = ac1 = ac, \tag{6}$

confirming k31453's calculation.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***